# Format percentages in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, format, spreadsheet

I am trying to format the following column in Microsoft Excel to add the percentage sign after the second decimal:

```
5.8394
3.2922
3.2
4.461
1
```

I highlight the column and choose Format cells > Percentage > Decimal places: 2 and get the following result:

```
583.94%
329.22%
320.00%
446.10%
100.00%
```

If I choose Decimal places: 0, I get the following:

```
 584%
 329%
 320%
 446%
 100%
```

How to I get Excel to show the original numbers as percentages without changing the values?

Answer (score 4):

Found this answer on a different site:

> Right Click, Format Cells, Custom. Manually type in "0.0\%" without
>   the quotes.
>
> If you want more decimal places to show, just add in zeroes. "0.000\%"
>
> For example, if your cell contents are '4.35' then with the above
>   custom format it would appear as '4.350%'.

Problem solved!

Comment: FYI, this also works in LibreOffice Calc.

Comment: It might display what you want, but you will need to divide by 100 if you want to use it in calculations. Which is why Excel defaults to interpreting 4.35 as 435%.

Answer (score 3):

1.0=100%, so it makes sense that if you set decimal place to 2 that it will show 100.00%.

If you would like them to be a percentage, try dividing them all by 100 first. Then choosing the percent formatting.

For example you will have 3.2/100=0.032, then when you change the cell to percent with 2 decimal places it will be 3.20%.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I understand what Excel is doing, I just think it's silly.  So the only way to do this is to run a divide operation every time I paste a new number into this column?  Is there really no way to simply tack on a percentage sign at the end?

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note:

If your cells are already populated with a number, lets say "5.8", and you apply the percentage formatting afterwards, the cell will display "580%."

If you apply the percentage formatting to blank cells, then type "5.8", the cell will display "5.8%."

Kind of weird, but try it out, and you will see

Answer (score 0):

Another method without needing the custom formatting (for those that aren't familiar with the codes) is to simply include the % sign when entering the numbers (which I think you queried in a comment?).

When pasting or typing these figures into Excel, it will then interpret the correct percentage amount and format. In the toolbar you can then just set this column to show 2 decimal places (in which the numbers are Rounded to fit).

I guess it depends on how you are getting those figures into the sheet and if you can add the percentage% sign in at the beginning.

Comment: This wouldn't work in many use cases, because the numbers are being pasted from another spreadsheet.

Comment: Unfortunately, "how" you were working with the numbers wasn't fully explained in original post.  If you mean, you are manually switching to Sheet 2 and "copying", then going to Sheet 1 and "pasting" the numbers, then simply enter the percentage sign on Sheet 2 first (at the point of data entry). If you mean the numbers on Sheet 1 are being formula derived from Sheet 2 numbers, then add the percentage sign onto the formula. If the original numbers on Sheet 2 are being generated by some other source, then see above two points.

Comment: Again this doesn't cover all cases.  If the column already has data and you are simply adding to it (especially if you're doing it on a regular basis), then you're in trouble because you'll continue to need to format existing data.  The solution I posted works perfectly.

Comment: I agree that your solution works in more cases.